# How to position element between two sections while also being responsive?

Tags: html, css, material-design, html-framework-7

First, here's an example I'm trying to achieve:
[image]

Here's the code I'm using to achieve that

**HTML**:

```
<div class="card demo-card-header-pic" style="margin:15px;">
            <div style="background-image:url(https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_banners/6253282/1431474710/web_retina)" valign="bottom" class="card-header color-white no-border"></div>
            <div class="avatar">
              <img src="http://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/2284174872/7df3h38zabcvjylnyfe3_bigger.png" style="border-radius:50px;">
            </div>
            <div class="card-content">
              <div class="card-content-inner">
                <div>
                  <p><b>****</b> wants to know what you think of him!</p>
                </div>
                <div>
                  <span class="text-muted" style="float:left;">Asked two days ago</span>
                  <span style="float:right;" class="text-muted"> 5 comments</span>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="card-footer">Footer</div>
          </div>
```

**CSS**:

```
.demo-card-header-pic .card-header
{
    height: 40vw;
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: center;
}
.avatar
{
    border-radius: 50px;
}
.card > .avatar
{
    position: relative;
    top: -40px;
    left:5px;
}
.text-muted {
    color: #777;
}
```

My question is how do I get rid of all the white space that is between the header of the card and the text? I tried using `position:absolute`but that would mess up anytime the display was changed, even when using percentages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A quick solution would be to give `.card-content` a negative margin-top value. I do agree that it's not the most elegant solution, but it get's the job done. Also adding a `clear:both` to the footer will prevent the overlay of both DIVs that you have at the moment

CSS:

```
.card-content{
   margin-top: -40px;
}

.card-footer{
    clear: both;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

just remove `margin` form your main div and also if you want to remove body default white space then use following css on body

```
body{
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}
```